# How do I select rows where CONTAINS looks for value of a column, not a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I figured this would already have been asked, but I couldn't find it on stack overflow.

I have a SQL Server table called `DataTable` with two columns `name` and `message`.  I want to select all the rows where "message" contains the same value as in the `name` column.

```
INSERT INTO DataTable values ('frank','this is frank's message');
INSERT INTO DataTable values ('jill','this is not frank's message');
```

I want to return only the first row, because the value in the [name] column ("frank") is in the column [message]

```
 SELECT [name],[message]  
 FROM  DataTable
 WHERE CONTAINS([message],[name])
```

This throws the error :

> Incorrect syntax near 'name'".

How do I write this correctly?

Comment: Are you using a fulltext index? CONTAINS is only valid in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `LIKE`, in case `[name]` can be contained as a part of `[message]` :

```
SELECT [name],[message]  
FROM  DataTable
WHERE [message] LIKE '%' + [name] + '%'
```

or you can use `=` operator in case `[name]` should be equal to `[message]`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm not that sure.)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try the use of "LIKE".  The "=" won't work for me because message could be a longer message, with just part of it having "[name]"

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE

```
SELECT name, message
FROM DataTable
WHERE message LIKE '%name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this.

```
insert into datatable values ('blabla','blabla')
                    insert into datatable values ('blabla1','blabla1')
                    insert into datatable values ('blabla1','blabla2')


                    select * from datatable where messages=name
```

results:

```
messages name
-------- --------
blabla   blabla  
blabla1  blabla1
```

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS requires two arguments and returns a number a result presenting true or false. It will be 1 (true) if it finds a match and 0 (false) if it doesn’t. The first argument is the name of the table column you want searched. The second argument is your substring you need. The basic syntax is as follows.

```
SELECT columnName FROM yourTable WHERE CONTAINS (columnName, ‘yourSubstring’);
```

From my example above, you should note that I did not enclose the column name in quotes, but I did enclose the arguments for the CONTAINS SQL function in parentheses.